# How to check palindrome with FILO in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, stack

I need to check if a text is a palindrome or not, through the concept of stacks, I have a function that creates the stack and another that will check if it is a palindrome stacking the word and unstacking it.

The problem is that I do not know how I can proceed to do this verification.

**My code :**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type ="text/javascript" />
         function FILO(){
                this.stack = new Array();

                this.Push = function(obj){
                this.stack[this.stack.length] =obj;
                }

        this.Pop =function(){
                if(this.stack.length>0){
                  var obj = this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
                  this.stack.splice(this.stack.length -1,1);
                  return obj;
              }else {
                alert("Theres no objects in the stack");

           }
          }
         }

        function palindrome() {
        var mystack = new FILO();
        var text1;
        var text2;
        var i;
        var t;
        text1 = prompt("Type a text: ");
        i = text1.length;
        t = text1.length;

        do{
            mystack.Push(text1.substr(t-i,1));
            i--;
        }while(i>0);

        do{
            text2 = mystack.Pop();
            document.write(text2, "</br>");
        }while(i>0);

        if(text1 === text2) {
        alert("It is a palindrome");
        }
        else {
        alert("It's not a palindrome");
        }

        }



    </script>

</head>


<body>
<h1>Verification of Palindrome </h1>
<p>Press the button to see if a word is a palindrome or not</p>

<form>
    <input type = "button" onClick ="palindrome()" value = "Verifiy">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But this code does not work, because when typing it says that there are no objects in the stack, and they do not end up being inserted so I can unstack. How can I make this work?

PS : I am new to JavaScript so the code it can be a messy thing, sorry for that.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the code, before this line "function palindrome() {" there is an extra }. Check it

Comment: try appending the letters to text2 to create the word backwards and then comparing `var text2 = ""; text2 += mystack.Pop();` then `if(text1 === text2)` you have a palindrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually very close. You just need to **concatenate** the popped letters together and then compare to `text1` (which you already do).

You also have a bug in your second `do while` you use the same iterator `i` as the first loop when you should probably be using your `t` variable and decrementing it. Here is the example with your fixed code

```js
function FILO() {
  this.stack = new Array();

  this.Push = function(obj) {
    this.stack[this.stack.length] = obj;
  }

  this.Pop = function() {
    if (this.stack.length > 0) {
      var obj = this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
      this.stack.splice(this.stack.length - 1, 1);
      return obj;
    } else {
      alert("Theres no objects in the stack");

    }
  }
}

function palindrome() {
  var mystack = new FILO();
  var text1;
  var text2 = "";
  var i;
  var t;
  text1 = prompt("Type a text: ");
  i = text1.length;
  t = text1.length;

  do {
    mystack.Push(text1.substr(t - i, 1));
    i--;
  } while (i > 0);

  do {
    text2 += mystack.Pop(); //Here this should be += instead of =
    t--
    document.write(text2, "</br>");
  } while (t > 0); //use and decrement t variable in this do while

  if (text1 === text2) {
    alert("It is a palindrome");
  } else {
    alert("It's not a palindrome");
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Verification of Palindrome </h1>
  <p>Press the button to see if a word is a palindrome or not</p>
  <form>
    <input type="button" onClick="palindrome()" value="Verifiy">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. So it was in the end, some smalls errors, I just saw now that I was not using the variable t. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var stack1 = [], stack2 = [];
var text1 = prompt('Type a text: ');
for(var i = 0, max = text1.length; i < max; i++) {
    stack1.push(text1[i]);
    stack2.push(text1[max - 1 - i]);
}

var isPalindrome = true;
while(stack1.length > 0) {
    if(stack1.pop() != stack2.pop()) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}

console.log('isPalindrome: ', isPalindrome);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code, but I have to use the function FILO, in the function palindrome, using for example. So it would have to be mystack.stack1.push. Could it work like that ? Because I have to instantiate the function FILO.